# How to use "#" in dotenv as value | nodejs

Tags: node.js, dotenv

I have logins and passwords.
As sample `LOGINS="sample1@mail.com","sample2@mail.com"` and `PASSWORDS="qwer123!@#","rewq4321$#@!"`

Passwords contain a `"#"`. And .env remove all after this symbol. If i try to console.log result is just `"qwer123!@"` without a second pass and `"#"`

I tried to use `"\"` but it`s do nothing

I expect to use my passwords array with special charcters

Comment: The first fix is to set PASSs as JSON, and parse it

Comment: Which dotenv library are you using? [this one](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv) says it should work if you just wrap the whole thing in quotes but your environment variables seem to be written in a way that would break this library

Comment: You could also give a different configuration package a try:  [wj-config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wj-config).  It is a JSON-based configuration package that does everything `dotenv` can and way, way more.  After Christmas I'll be releasing the first Release Candidate.

Comment: @apokryfos i use standart dontenv package. I resolve this problem just put all passwords as a single string and splitting it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way, Put all passwords in single string separated by `,` and then split them so it would give an array.

```
// .env
PASSWORDS="qwer123!@#,rewq4321$#@!"
```

and call the env value like this

```
const passwords = process.env.PASSWORDS?.split(',');
// Output: [ 'qwer123!@#asda', 'rewq4321$#@!' ]
```

Metadata: I've used `dotenv` package in order to access the env variables from process.

Comment: Yep, this is correct. I used the same logic to get it as an array from env. The issue was with multiple strings. Change to a single string resolved it